# How to choose the best matching localization language from list

Tags: localization, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

My windows store application gets localized strings from database. Each string is stored with language code (en-US, en-CA, en-AU, etc.). How can I determine the best matching language for my application if my current system locale is en-US?

It looks like [a NamedResource.Resolve(ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206048.aspx) could be a solution, but I cannot find the way to create [a NamedResource.Candidates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.namedresource.candidates.aspx) list from code.